# How do I rewrite a subtree with a composite root using ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have an antlr grammer with subtrees like this:

```
 ^(type ID)
```

that I want to convert to:

```
 ^(type DUMMY ID)
```

where type is 'a'|'b'.

Note: what I really want to do is convert anonymous instantiations to explicit by generating dummy names.

I've narrowed it down to the grammars below, but I'm getting this:

```
(a bar) (b bar)
got td
got bu
Exception in thread "main" org.antlr.runtime.tree.RewriteEmptyStreamException: rule type
        at org.antlr.runtime.tree.RewriteRuleElementStream._next(RewriteRuleElementStream.java:157)
        at org.antlr.runtime.tree.RewriteRuleSubtreeStream.nextNode(RewriteRuleSubtreeStream.java:77)
        at Pattern.bu(Pattern.java:382)
```

The error message continues. My debug so far:

1. The input made it through the initial grammar generating two trees. a bar and b bar.
2. The second grammar does match the trees. it's printing td and bu.
3. The rewrite crashes, but I have no idea why? What does RewriteEmptyStreamException mean.

**What the proper way to do this kind of a rewrite?**

My main grammer Rewrite.g:

```
grammar Rewrite;

options {
  output=AST;
}

@members{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      RewriteLexer lexer = new RewriteLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("a foo\nb bar"));
      RewriteParser parser = new RewriteParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.test().getTree();
      System.out.println(tree.toStringTree());

      CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(tree);        
      Pattern p = new Pattern(nodes);

      CommonTree newtree = (CommonTree) p.downup(tree);
  }
}

type 
    : 'a'
    | 'b'
    ;

test : id+;
id   : type ID  -> ^(type ID["bar"]);

DUMMY : 'dummy';
ID   : ('a'..'z')+;
WS : (' '|'\n'|'r')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

and Pattern.g

```
tree grammar Pattern;

options {
    tokenVocab = Rewrite;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    output=AST;
    filter=true;             // tree pattern matching mode
}

topdown
    : td
    ;

bottomup
    : bu
    ;

type 
    : 'a'
    | 'b'
    ;

td
    : ^(type ID) { System.out.println("got td"); }
    ;

bu
    : ^(type ID) { System.out.println("got bu"); }
        -> ^(type DUMMY ID)
    ;
```

to do compile:

```
java -cp ../jar/antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar org.antlr.Tool Rewrite.g 
java -cp ../jar/antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar org.antlr.Tool Pattern.g 
javac -cp ../jar/antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar *.java 
java -classpath .:../jar/antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar RewriteParser
```

EDIT 1: I have also tried using antlr4 and I get the same crash.

Comment: Excellent question, btw. A proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that others can see the exact error you're seeing!

Answer (score 2):

There are two small problems to address to get the rewrite to work, one problem in `Rewrite` and the other in `Pattern`.

The `Rewrite` grammar produces `^(type ID)` as root elements in the output AST, as shown in the output `(a bar) (b bar)`.  A root element can't be transformed because transforming is actually a form of child-swapping: the element's parent drops the element and replaces it with the new, "transformed" version. Without a parent, you'll get the error `Can't set single child to a list`. Adding the root is a matter of creating an imaginary token `ROOT` or whatever name you like and referencing it in your entry-level rule's AST generation like so: `test : id+ -> ^(ROOT id+);`.

The `Pattern` grammar, the one producing the error you're getting, is confused by the `type` rule: `type : 'a' | 'b' ;` as part of the rewrite. I don't know the low-level details here, but apparently a tree parser doesn't maintain the state of a visited root rule like `type` in `^(type ID)` when writing a transform  (or maybe it can't or shouldn't, or maybe it's some other limitation). The easiest way to address this is with the following two changes:

- Let text "a" and "b" match rule `ID` in the lexer by changing rule `type` in `Rewrite` from `type: 'a' | 'b';` to just `type: ID;`.
- Let rule `bu` in `Pattern` match against `^(ID ID)` and transform to `^(ID DUMMY ID)`.

Now with a couple of minor debugging changes to `Rewrite`'s `main`, input `"a foo\nb bar"` produces the following output:

```
(ROOT (a foo) (b bar))
got td
got bu
(a foo) -> (a DUMMY foo)
got td
got bu
(b bar) -> (b DUMMY bar)
(ROOT (a DUMMY foo) (b DUMMY bar))
```

Here are the files as I've changed them:

#### Rewrite.g

```
grammar Rewrite;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens { 
 ROOT;
}

@members{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      RewriteLexer lexer = new RewriteLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("a foo\nb bar"));
      RewriteParser parser = new RewriteParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.test().getTree();
      System.out.println(tree.toStringTree());

      CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(tree);        
      Pattern p = new Pattern(nodes);

      CommonTree newtree = (CommonTree) p.downup(tree, true); //print the transitions to help debugging
      System.out.println(newtree.toStringTree()); //print the final result
  }
}

type : ID;
test : id+ -> ^(ROOT id+);
id   : type ID  -> ^(type ID);

DUMMY : 'dummy';
ID   : ('a'..'z')+;
WS : (' '|'\n'|'r')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

#### Pattern.g

```
tree grammar Pattern;

options {
    tokenVocab = Rewrite;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    output=AST;
    filter=true;             // tree pattern matching mode
}

topdown
    : td
    ;

bottomup
    : bu
    ;

td
    : ^(ID ID) { System.out.println("got td"); }
    ;

bu
    : ^(ID ID) { System.out.println("got bu"); }
        -> ^(ID DUMMY ID)
    ;
```

Comment: the single child info is very helpful. Thank you. On using ID instead of a|b, doesn't the defeat the purpose of using a lexer/parser? My actual grammar is more complex. a and b are one of many IDs that a tree can start with. I only want the ones with a and b. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mmccoo You can describe "a" and "b" using whatever token works best for you (I tucked "a" and "b" into `ID` since `ID` already described them) as long as you end up with a particular token to match against in `Pattern`. For example, say lexer rule `TYPE` is `TYPE: 'a'|'b';` and token parser rule `id` is `id: TYPE ID;`. Then `Pattern`'s `bu` becomes `bu: ^(TYPE ID) -> ^(TYPE DUMMY ID);`. I can update my answer if it would help.

Comment: @mmccoo Another thing to note, if you weren't aware, is that using a string in a parser rule quietly creates a new lexer rule behind the scenes. So token rule `type: 'a' | 'b';` is treated like `type: SOMERULE_A | SOMERULE_B;`, where `SOMERULE_A` and `SOMERULE_B` are new, *unrelated* lexer rules that match "a" and "b", respectively (I don't know what they're actually named, since they aren't visible in the normal sense). Testing for "a" and "b" in the lexer explicitly, as in `TYPE: 'a' | 'b';`, makes transforming trees and tracking down token-related problems easier.

Comment: my initial response was, "yes! That's it.".... but. when I did that some of the other lex rules that look for a|c and a|b|c become unreachable. All of this leaves me wonder whether people actually use rewrite. Seems super useful, but I don't see a lot of traffic about it on google.

Comment: @mmccoo The "unreachable lexer rule" warning is a pretty common ANTLR problem that, for better or worse, is unrelated to the rewrite. I think rewrites are undervalued, but I suspect that most ANTLR grammars out there aren't complex enough to justify using them or people are content to manipulate the AST output in strange ways from within the token parser (unlike Bart K's example, which is a useful way to avoid writing a token-inserting rewriter).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with tree-patterns, with or without rewrites. But when using rewrite rules in them, I believe your options should also include `rewrite=true;`. The Definitive ANTLR Reference doesn't handle them, so I'm not entirely sure (have a look at the [ANTLR wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki) for more info).

However, for such (relatively) simple rewrites, you don't really need a separate grammar. You could make `DUMMY` an imaginary token and *inject* it in some other parser rule, like this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  DUMMY;
}

test : id+;
id   : type ID  -> ^(type DUMMY["dummy"] ID);

type 
 : 'a'
 | 'b'
 ;

ID : ('a'..'z')+;
WS : (' '|'\n'|'r')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

which would parse the input:

```
a bar 
b foo
```

into the following AST:

[image]

Note that if your lexer is also meant to tokenize the input `"dummy"` as a `DUMMY` token, change the `tokens { ... }` block into this:

```
tokens {
  DUMMY='dummy';
}
```

and you'd still be able to *inject* a `DUMMY` in other rules.